# The _M_decrement function implemention in stl_tree.h in SGI STL about rbtree

Tags: c++, stl, tree

At the end of _M_increment function,

```
if (_M_node->_M_right != __y)
      _M_node = __y;
```

deal with the situation where the previous node is the largest value, and assign header node (__y) to _M_node.

```
void _M_increment()
{
  if (_M_node->_M_right != 0)
  {
    _M_node = _M_node->_M_right;
    while (_M_node->_M_left != 0)
      _M_node = _M_node->_M_left;
  }
  else
  {
    _Base_ptr __y = _M_node->_M_parent;
    while (_M_node == __y->_M_right)
    {
      _M_node = __y;
      __y = __y->_M_parent;
    }
    if (_M_node->_M_right != __y)
      _M_node = __y;
  }
}
```

But in _M_decrement function, there isn't the similar code to deal with the similar situation where the previous is the smallest value.

```
void _M_decrement()
{
  if (_M_node->_M_color == _S_rb_tree_red &&
    _M_node->_M_parent->_M_parent == _M_node)
  _M_node = _M_node->_M_right;
  else if (_M_node->_M_left != 0)
  {
    _Base_ptr __y = _M_node->_M_left;
    while (__y->_M_right != 0)
      __y = __y->_M_right;
    _M_node = __y;
  }
  else {
    _Base_ptr __y = _M_node->_M_parent;
    while (_M_node == __y->_M_left)
    {
      _M_node = __y;
      __y = __y->_M_parent;
    }
    _M_node = __y;
  }
}
```

Is it legal that the decrement function dosen't have the similar code to judge the boundary condition? 
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is not allowed to decrement `begin()`. It is allowed to increment the iterator right before `end()`.

Comment: @T.C. you are right.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I didn't understand the reason why the decrement didn't have the similar code. T.C. 's comment is right. Thank you for you two.

Comment: Maybe ask a question? This is a Q&A site.